# Jetty Eclipse connection error: The method dumpStdErr() is undefined for the type Server

Tags: eclipse, jetty

I am trying to write a helloWorld for **Jetty server** in eclipse using this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html). However, I couldn't figure out what library includes " dumpStdErr() " since is is undefined by my compiler. Is there any alternatives for this function?

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server; 

/*
* The simplest possible Jetty server.
*/ 
    public class SimplestServer { public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    server.start();
    server.dumpStdErr();
    server.join(); } }
```

Comment: Are you using the same version of Jetty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using a recent/stable version of Jetty in your dependencies.

See: http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html

The `dumpStdError()` method [was added in Jetty 7.3.0](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/e10c14c77aee8c4c0aaf1b7cd0def390239dbf2b) and has been in every version since.

> Note: [Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 are EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), do not use them anymore.  Upgrade to Jetty 9 at your first opportunity.